# How can I write a native templated backing storage for a generic interface?

Tags: .net, c++, templates, generics, interop

I have an interface, say;

```
public interface ICustomCollection<T>
{
     void Add(T item);
     bool Remove(T item);
     bool Contains(T item);
}
```

I would like to create a class that access native C/C++ dll (which I'd also create) which provide the implementation. How can I go about writing the managed class and native code for this to work? I know interop basics but I don't know how to handle generic types in this context.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a slight shift in your thinking and require that T be an interface type that derives from Object, and you should, then the C++ interface becomes a lot more obvious.

Comment: I should say the C++/CLI interface should become obvious because you won't be writing a pure C++ DLL.

Answer (score 0):

This builds fine in Visual Studio 2010:

```
template<class T>
public interface class ICustomCollection
{
     virtual void Add(T item);
     virtual bool Remove(T item);
     virtual bool Contains(T item);
};

template<class T>
public ref class GenericCustomCollection : ICustomCollection<T>
{
    virtual void Add(T item){ }
    virtual bool Remove(T item){ return false; }
    virtual bool Contains(T item){ return false; }
};

public ref class ConcreteCustomCollection : ICustomCollection<int>
{
public:
    virtual void Add(int item){ }
    virtual bool Remove(int item){ return false; }
    virtual bool Contains(int item){ return false; }
};
```

I just made the minimum needed for it to build, you can use this as a starting point for your implementation.

If you're getting started with C++/CLI, this is a good book: [Expert C++/CLI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597567)